# Using button to display a data table

Tags: gui-construction, button

Here is the code I have tried:

```
Button["Click to show table", Grid[data]]
```

Is there a way to do this, so the user can click a button to show the data table?

Comment: just add `Print`: that is use `Print@ Grid[data]`

Comment: There are several options depending on what you want.  You could have an output cell `Dynamic@griddata`, and change your button to `Button["Click to show table", griddata = Grid[data]]`. You could call up a new window with each click with the code `Button["Click to show table", CreateDocument@Grid[data]]`.  These approaches can be tweaked in ways depending on what is desired.